# Possible to include only images for iPad version?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm in the process of making my iPhone application compatible with the iPad. I want to include larger image files for higher resolution artwork for the iPad version that I don't want included in the iPhone version (don't want the binary to become huge). Is there a way to accomplish this, or am I pretty much stuck with having to include the iPad art work with the iPhone version and vice versa?

Comment: A universal app (iPhone and iPad) must have everything for both. That's how it works.

Comment: You could host them remotely and download on the iPad. This is very dependent on your usecase, however.

Comment: And how big are these images?  Is it worth the complexity of doing this to save a bit of space - when the user on these platforms barely notices the size of apps.

Comment: @iandotkelly - I think including them will increase my project size from 25 to about 50-60 maybe more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include both for a universal app, but as of iOS7 and when you use an Asset Catalog, the user won't have to download any unnecessary images. Apple takes care of this for you.

[Asset Catalog Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Quote:

> For projects with a deployment target of iOS 7, Xcode compiles your asset catalogs into a runtime binary file format that reduces the download time for your app.

Comment: THanks for that. That's too bad they can only be used for projects with a deployment target of iOS7, guess I'll have to wait till next year to utilize them.

Comment: This doesn't appear to reduce the number of images that need to be downloaded, it just simply appears to be making the images take up less space. It says nothing about excluding images depending on which device it's installed on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have one version in the store, it must include both. But if you want to have separate iPad and iPhone versions, then they each only need the images for that version. Just have two separate targets in the Xcode project for each, and make sure that you only have the assets included for the versions that need them.